# Any way to convert css3 animation to canvas animation?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I need to make the gif image by canvas from [this](https://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/).

Is there any way to convert css3 animation to canvas animation?

I am looking for some awesome text animations, but it always made by css3. I just wonder there is an easy way to convert or I need to rewrite it by myself.

Thanks !

Comment: you need to write it on yourself. No other way.

Comment: You have to write it on your own. Maybe this overview of HTML5 animation possibilities helps: [Animate your HTML5](http://animateyourhtml5.appspot.com/pres/)

Answer (score 2):

**Here's one way to use html5 canvas to capture animations into a .GIF**

The Greensock Animation Library is an excellent animation library that can manipulate DOM elements just like CSS3 animations.

But importantly for you, *Greensock can also animate any javascript object*.

This means that you can:

1. Create a JS object that draws individual animation frames on html5 canvas based on that JSObject's properties. For example:

   ```
   // create a JSObject capable of drawing a rotating rectangle
   var RotatingRect={
       cx:canvas.width/2,
       cy:canvas.height/2,
       w:50,
       h:35,
       ww:-50/2,
       hh:-35/2,
       rangle:0,
       draw:function(){
           ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
           ctx.translate(this.cx,this.cy);
           ctx.rotate(this.rangle);
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.rect(this.ww,this.hh,this.w,this.h);
           ctx.closePath();
           ctx.fill();
           ctx.stroke();
           ctx.rotate(-this.rangle);
           ctx.translate(-this.cx,-this.cy);
           ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
       },
   }
   ```
2. Use Greensock to drive the animation by changing the JSObject's properties.
   and then requesting that redrawing each "frame" on the canvas. Greensock has an `onUpdate` event triggers each time Greensock

   ```
   // Use Greensock to animate from RotatingRect's current angle
   var tl=TweenLite.to(RotatingRect,5,{    
       paused:true,
       rangle:PI2*2,
       ease:"Quart.easeOut",
       onUpdate:function(){this.target.draw();},
       onComplete:function(){log('complete',RotatingRect);}
     }
   );
   ```
3. Optionally, use GifJS to add a new GIF frame whenever the Greensock causes a new canvas frame to be drawn.

   ```
   // Add to the bottom of RotatingRect.draw()
   // Add a GIF frame from the current canvas content
   gif.addFrame(canvasElement);
   ```

**Tools:**

[The Greensock Animation Library](http://greensock.com/gsap)

[The gifJS Script](https://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/)

[The Html5 Canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial)

**Here is example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray';
ctx.lineWidth=3;


var PI=Math.PI;
var PI2=PI*2;


var RotatingRect={
  cx:canvas.width/2,
  cy:canvas.height/2,
  w:50,
  h:35,
  ww:-50/2,
  hh:-35/2,
  rangle:0,
  draw:function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.translate(this.cx,this.cy);
    ctx.rotate(this.rangle);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.ww,this.hh,this.w,this.h);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-this.rangle);
    ctx.translate(-this.cx,-this.cy);
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  },
}

// Use Greensock to animate from RotatingRect's current angle
var tl=TweenLite.to(RotatingRect,5,{    
  paused:true,
  rangle:PI2*2,
  ease:"Quart.easeOut",
  onUpdate:function(){this.target.draw();},
  onComplete:function(){log('complete',RotatingRect);}
}
                   );


RotatingRect.draw();

$('#play').click(function(){ tl.play(); });

$('#replay').click(function(){  tl.restart(); });
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js"></script>

<button id=play>Play</button>
<button id=replay>Replay</button>
<br><canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```